# Importing Pillow on MSYS2 Leads To _Imaging Module Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, mingw, msys2

Recently, I set up an MSYS2 installation on my Win11 computer. It's extremely bare-bones, having been set up for less than a day.

I am trying to use that installation to run a simple Python program using PIL, but am never able to get into the body of the code. Whenever I try, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/d/PythonTest/txt2img.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 103, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

from the code:

```
# coding=utf8

import PIL
from PIL import Image
```

What confuses me is the nature of that error. When I have seen this in the past or on stackoverflow, the nature of that ImportError is usually a dll or shared object file failing. However, I appear to be unable to determine what component piece is failing. I can see that _imaging exists in the installation:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 None 1833444 Jun 13 18:14 /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-x86_64-msys.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 None   71604 Jun 13 18:14 /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imagingmath.cpython-311-x86_64-msys.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 None   42065 Jun 13 18:14 /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imagingmorph.cpython-311-x86_64-msys.dll
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 None   55416 Jun 13 18:14 /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imagingtk.cpython-311-x86_64-msys.dll
```

It was able to import PIL. I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times after upgrading the packages for a number of dependencies, including but not limited to:

```
mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
mingw-w64-x86_64-python3
mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-pip
mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-setuptools
mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo
mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib
mingw-w64-x86_64-libtiff
mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype
mingw-w64-x86_64-lcms2
mingw-w64-x86_64-libwebp
mingw-w64-x86_64-openjpeg2
mingw-w64-x86_64-libimagequant
mingw-w64-x86_64-libraqm
```

I have the following pip packages installed:

```
# pip list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
certifi            2023.5.7
charset-normalizer 3.1.0
cPython            0.0.6
dnspython          2.3.0
idna               3.4
Pillow             9.5.0
pip                23.1.2
pymongo            4.3.3
requests           2.31.0
urllib3            2.0.3
```

The fact that it's not able to find _imaging stands out to me as not being able to recognize the cpython file, but I cannot figure out why this would be the case. I would expect permissions issues, but I can't see why my current permissions would not be up to task.

Comment: Try `print(sys.executable)` to see which Python interpreter & version you are running. Then try `pip show Pillow` to see where `pip` installed that and if it matches where your Python is looking.

Comment: I'm seeing Python version 3.11.3 installed as /usr/bin/python.exe, while pip verifies that the location Pillow is installed to is /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages. Both are about what I would expect.